# Linux Bash String Concatenation Issue

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to read the first line from a CSV file and then from the two entries build up a string to be used as a filename later on.  The code I have is as follows:-

```
#Read TXT File to get Plan Number and Letter Type
while IFS=, read -r plan lettype
do
    p="${plan/\//~}"
    q="$lettype"
    r="${p}_$q"
    echo $r
done < "$j"
```

`$r` is echoing out `320529~14_NEA` at the moment.

the first line of the csv file is normally something like `320529/14,NEA` and I need to get to something like this into a variable

```
320529~14_NEA_NA_NA_131624733749396662.TIF
```

The `_NA_NA_` and `.TIFF` are static and the long number is some kind of timestamp but for the moment I am happy to work with the output from $(date +%s).

--Update--
Thanks for the two suggestions so far - neither work though.  This is what I have tried.

```
  if [ -f $j ]; then
    echo "File $j exists."

    name="$(head -n1 ${j})_NA_NA_$(date +%s).TIFF"
    echo $name

    #Read TXT File to get Plan Number and Letter Type
    while IFS=, read -r plan lettype
    do
            p="${plan/\//~}"
            q="$lettype"
            r="${p}_$q_NA_NA_$(date +%s).TIFF"
            s="${p}_${q}_NA_NA_$(date +%s).TIFF"
            echo $r
            echo $s
    done < "$j"
  else
    echo "File $j does not exist yet."
  fi
```

outputs

```
File ./GG11HH1J.TXT exists.
_NA_NA_1518009847.TIFF
320529~14_1518009847.TIFF
_NA_NA_1518009847.TIFF
```

--Update2--
Thanks to @triplee I now have the answer.  it was a DOS line ending.  Stripping it out and it all worked as expected.  Code used was:-

```
    fname=$(cat $j | sed 's/\r$//')
    fname="${fname/\//~}_NA_NA_$(date +%s).TIFF"
    fname=${fname/,/_}
    echo $fname
```

Comment: So what's preventing you from adding `"_NA_NA_$(date +%s).TIFF"` to the string you have? What's your actual question?

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason - please see update above

Comment: Do you have DOS carriage returns in the input file, or the script, by any chance?

Comment: Quite possibly - it is a file created in DOS believe it or not :-)

Comment: Happy to accept as a duplicate if I knew how to - it was def the line endings.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Normally when somebody with 2k+ rep flags as duplicate it asks you if that's correct and then that's it. I can't do that because I have enough [tag:bash] rep that it will unilaterally close the ticket when I nominate it as duplicate, and I didn't want to do that until we had confirmed that this was indeed the problem. All good now, thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
name="$(head -n1 inputFile)_NA_NA_$(date +%s).TIF"
```

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason - please see update above